# ADFS port with active directory

Tags: adfs

I have an ADFS server in DMZ and need it to talk to a DC. Which port does ADFS use to talk to a Domain controller in active directory?

Thanks

Comment: Google `ADFS ports required`. Seriously. I'm not even going to take the time to paste the first result into this comment - you put forth no effort here.

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](http://ahandyblog.wordpress.com/cloud-technologies/firewall-ports-for-office-365/), just TCP:443 bi-directional.

Although if I was you, I'd open up the firewall, and wireshark the connections, then make an informed decision based on that.